# Get position of private object in update method

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, skspritenode

Is there a way I can access a property of an SKSpriteNode (Its position) in the update() method if it is declared and initiated within a specific method? I have a method called shootLaser() that creates an SKSpriteNode like so:

```
var laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LaserDot.png")
```

And I need to perform an action using the position of "laser" every time a frame is rendered, and I only know of doing that by using the update() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the certain node by its `name` property:

```
laserNode.name = "laserNode"
```

After that , you can use [childNodeWithName](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName:) to access certain node by its name:

```
 let laserNode: SKSpriteNode = parentNode.childNodeWithName("laserNode") as SKSpriteNode
```

or if laser is added directly to the scene:

```
let laserNode: SKSpriteNode = childNodeWithName("laserNode") as SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: the update() method cant seem to find any node with that name /:

Comment: @Lahav Are  you sure you have properly set laserNode.name to "laserNode" before you have added the laserNode to the scene (or whatever other parent node) ?

Comment: Yes. I think that because the object with the name "laserNode" is private, "laserNode" isn't associated with anything outside the method

Comment: @Lahav If you are adding a node to the node tree inside that method, its there . It is not private. I will update my answer with an example. And it would be helpful if you can update your question with the code which can produce described behaviour.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It turns out that the method in which I declare and initialize the "laser" node had not yet been called, so no childNode with the name "laserNode" existed at the time, but I fixed it. Thanks for your solution, no need for further explanation (:

Comment: @Lahav Okay, no problem :) I am glad you've solved it.